# Hibernate many-to-many retrieve list with condition

Tags: java, hibernate

Im working with `hibernate` and `java`. I have an `Group` class and a `User` class. They share a `many-to-many` relationship as shown in this `ERD` [image: ERD].

What Im trying to achieve is that I want to retrieve a list of groups with the condition that they contain a `User` with a certain `User_id`.

In the `GroupDao` I have defined a function `retrieveForUser` in which I tried to retrieve the list using `hibernate query language`:

```
public List<Group> retrieveForUser(int userid){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "select distinct g from Group g " +
            "join g.allGroupMembers u " +
            "where u.id = :id";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    query.setParameter("id", userid);
    List<Group> list = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return list;
}
```

When I try to loop throught the resulting list using:

```
for(Group g : groupDao.retrieveForUser(user1.getId())){
    System.out.println(g.getName());
}
```

I get the following errormessage:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to nl.hu.jelo.domain.group.Group
```

**Question**
How can I achieve it so that I end up with an `List<Group>` with only groups that contain a `User` with an certain `User_id`

Comment: `setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);` is not required.  Why did you put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set result transformer. `ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP` is for other purpose.

Simply do

```
String hql = "select distinct g from Group g " +
        "join g.allGroupMembers u " +
        "where u.id = :id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id", userid);
```

is good enough.

Something off topic, are you sure you want to handle transaction manually like that?